# Show that the set of $n\times{n}$ matrices paired with matrix addition forms an infinite abelian group.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

I am trying to show that the set of $n\times{n}$ matrices paired with matrix addition forms an infinite abelian group. clearly matrix addition is commutative hence is abelian. But how does one show it's an infinite group? do I show no element exist with a finite order? Or is it simply for any $A\in{M_n(\mathbb{R})}$ ${\nexists{k\in{\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}}}}$ s.t. $kA=0$.

Comment: As a vector space, $M_n(\Bbb R)\cong \Bbb R^{n^2}$, which is infinite. Hence the abelian group is infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second property is what you want. If $M$ is not identically the zero matrix, you should argue that $kM$ has a nonzero coordinate for any integer $k$. If you can show this, this implies that $M$ does not have finite order in $(M_n(\mathbb R),+)$.

In fact this shows something stronger than that your group is infinite, it actually shows that the group is *torsion-free*.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that there is an element which does not have finite order, take for instance the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0_{1 \times (n-1)} \\ 0_{(n-1) \times 1} & 0_{(n-1) \times (n-1)} \end{pmatrix}$.

Alternatively, you can see that each entry in the matrix is an element of $\mathbb{R}$, so there are infinite choices for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Your group contains an isomorphic copy of the additive group $\mathbb{R}$, which is infinite, of course.

Comment: or $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Z$